# Exportar DB SQL a AZURE

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql, ssms

Tengo una base de datos creada en SSMS, la cual usa `Windows Authetication`, la cuestión es que quiero subirla a Azure pero se presenta este error:

> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or
>   batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> The connection is broken and recovery is not possible.  The client
>   driver attempted to recover the connection one or more times and all
>   attempts failed.  Increase the value of ConnectRetryCount to increase
>   the number of recovery attempts. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 0)
>
> For help, click:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=0&LinkId=20476
>
> ---
>
> Cannot open database "SIKOR" requested by the login. The login failed.
>   Login failed for user 'IKOR'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 4060)

- Ya agregue la IP al firewall
- Ya verifique que tenga la contraseña y el nombre de usuario bien y el servidor creado en azure esta bien, de hecho logro conectarme en el SSMS, usando las mismas credenciales.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A que se debe que no pueda continuar? Sera la autenticación?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure SQL Database solamente usa SQL Authentication y autenticaciones basadas en Azure Active Directory. Para subirla a Azure te recomiendo la herramienta [Data Migration Assistant](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595) que es la forma más fácil de subir una base de datos a Azure SQL Database.